# Interrogation about elasticsearch node and transport clients

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have configured an application to use the elasticsearch node client in test and the elasticsearch transport client in production/cloud and in dev.

I end up with a **`data`** directory in my project when I run the tests.

See following directory structure:

```
data
└── elasticsearch
    └── nodes
        └── 0
            ├── node.lock
            └── _state
                └── global-2
```

Here is my cloud/dev config:

```
@Configuration
@Profile({ Profiles.CLOUD, Profiles.DEV })
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.bignibou.repository.elasticsearch")
public class ElasticsearchConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate() {
        return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client());
    }

    @Bean
    public Client client() {
        TransportClient client = new TransportClient();
        // TODO: Externalize & use spring cloud connector
        TransportAddress address = new InetSocketTransportAddress("localhost", 9300);
        client.addTransportAddress(address);
        return client;
    }
}
```

Here is my test config:

```
@Profile(Profiles.TEST)
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.bignibou.repository.elasticsearch")
public class TestElasticsearchConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate() {
        return new ElasticsearchTemplate(nodeBuilder().local(true).node().client());
    }

}
```

Can someone please explain what is this **`data`** directory and whether is is written by the node client or the transport client?